# How to get NFTs Information by name with web3.js on solana network

Tags: web3js, solana, nft, solana-web3js

I would start saying that i'm completely new to this world of web3.
What i would like to do is :

Retrieve info's of NFTs from solana network.I would like to retrieve the info by the name.

From reading metaplex documentation and https://docs.solana.com/ i guess it's impossible to do so.

So does i have to do something like this:

Connect to candy machine and find all the nfts and save them in the db with all info's and than obviously make calls to db by name?

My goal is to have all the info's of nft and allow end user to search it by the name.

Any help is appreciated. Just need a path or any little suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to search things on Solana, you have to give the account that you want to search and then deserialize its info. In this case each NFT has its own account on solana (you can get all accounts that were minted from a CandyMachine (all NFTs).

The deserialization part given an ID is really easy using [js-next](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-next#findByMint) library provided by metaplex. So you just have to find all NFTs that were minted from a CandyMachine (you can use [metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/snapshot.html#snapshot-mints) or a [rpc call](https://docs.solana.com/es/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api)).

When you deserialize the NFT you will have access to its name and json metadata url so you can do whatever you want with that info.

Comment: S owhat you mean is this:
`const mint = new PublicKey("candy machine address");

const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint(mint)` ;?

Comment: Its not "candy machine address" is the "nft address"

Comment: But how do i find all the nft address's?

Comment: You can use metaboss, use getProgramAccount rpc calls, use a webpage that fetch minted nfts from a CM

Comment: Thanks, it was really useful. Do you have discord?